# optimization based interpretation of Bayes' theorem

Tags: bayesian, equivalence

I read about one equivalent interpretation of bayes' theorem as follows:

$P(\mathcal{M}|x) = \frac{P(x|\mathcal{M})\cdot\pi(\mathcal{M})}{\int P(x|\mathcal{M})\cdot\pi(\mathcal{M}) d\mathcal{M}}$ is equivalent to following optimization problem:

$\min_{q(\mathcal{M})} KL(q(\mathcal{M}) || \pi(\mathcal{M})) - \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathcal{M})} [\log p(x|\mathcal{M})]$

$s.t.q(\mathcal{M}) \in P_{prob} $

where $\pi(\mathcal{M})$ is the prior distribution, $P(x|\mathcal{M})$ is the likelihood, $KL$ is the KL divergence, $P_{prob}$ denotes properly normalized distributions. Could you please explain the intuition and how the second one can be derived from the standard first definition?